# I want to navigate to another page in ejs using a link

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to navigate to next page using link but i'm facing 404 error 
I'd changed my template from jade to ejs

```
<html>
  <body>
   <div>
      <ul style="color:white; float: right;" class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/login">Login   </a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sign Up </a>  </li>

        </ul>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show js file.

Answer (score 14):

@Asad, in order for you to go to `/login`, you must have this route declared in your server side. Something like:

```
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login');
   });
```

Otherwise, you will always have 404.

Comment: would i have to include these lines every time i want to redirect to a page

Comment: Well, it depends what you wanna do... But yeah, you should have a route for everywhere you wanna go. Try to read a little bit of the Express docs about routes.

And could you please mark as the best answer? :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using the following dependencies NPM:

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "ejs": "^3.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.13.20"
```

In app.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

In Ejs File:

```
<a class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" href="/someFile" >Link to some EJS File</a>
```

your file structure:

```
project
 node modules
 public
 views
  index.ejs
  someFile.ejs
```

By setting the view engine to ejs in the app.js file and setting the static file folder in the same app.js you may be able to call out to other ejs files in the same directory utilizing "/" for href. Hope this helps. This is my first answer on Stackoverflow so take it easy on me.

Answer (score 0):

["Image for Navigating Different Web Pages"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqi7t.jpg)

As illustrated in the image above, the best way to navigate different web pages using `ejs` template is to ensure you create a folder called "partials" in your project's "views folder directory" where you have your other ejs files.

1) Then in that "partials folder" create 2 separate ejs files called `header.ejs` & `footer.ejs`.

2) Then go to your `home.ejs` or `index.ejs` file depending on how you have named your starting ejs file, and then cut ("All contents including the css and probably the bootstrap links in the boiler plate down to the opening body tag `<body>` and paste in the `header.ejs` file in the partials folder").

3) Also cut ("All contents from the closing body tag `</body>` of the "home or `index.ejs` " file to the `footer.ejs` file in the partials folder"). Then instead of repeating the header and footer sections for the subsequent pages i.e `about.ejs` or `contact.ejs` just link them to the `header.ejs` and `footer.ejs` files in the partialss folder as below:

//Sample page of the about.ejs file

Visual Illustration:

```
<%- include("partials/header"); -%>

<h1> About Page </h1>

<p> This is an about page </p>


<%- include("partials/footer"); -%>
```

//Do same for other pages.

Finally, following the image above, link the navigation to the different pages at the anchor tags in the `header.ejs` file which is located in the partials folder using:

"/" ----- To Home Page.
"/about" ------ To About Page.
"/contact" ------ To Cntact Page.

I hope this helps. Please let me know your views.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this should be on your `login.ejs` page. Also, pay attention to spellings and all.

```
<a href="/login">...</a>
```

In server file

```
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {

    res.render('login');
    
    });
```

I faced the same issue and that's how I got it fixed.
And the login file should actually be created.

Answer (score 0):

App js.

```
const express = require("express");
const ejs = require("ejs");

const startingContent = "Home Page";
const aboutContent ="About Us Page";

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

> No Need for body parser, express handles that already, by using : app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true})); .

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));


app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
  res.render("home", {homeStart: startingContent});
});

    

app.get("/about", (req, res)=>{
  res.render("about", {aboutStartingText: aboutContent});
});


app.listen(3000, ()=> {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Site</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <p class="navbar-brand">My Site</p>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <!-- 6 -->
        <li id="home"><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
        <li id="about"><a href="/about">ABOUT US</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

<body>
  <div class="container">
```

Answer (score 0):

Header.ejs

> Best practice is to have your header and footer in a folder partials
> Example :
> views

```
partials
  header.ejs
  footer.ejs
home.ejs
about.ejs
```

Then you render in your ejs file.

```
<%- include("partials/header") -%>

<h1>Home</h1>
<p><%= homeStart %></p>

<%- include("partials/footer") -%>
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

Routes in *.js:

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.render("home", { contentHome: homeStartingContent});
});

app.get("/about", function (req, res) {
  res.render("about", { contentAboutpage: aboutContent });
});

app.get("/contact", function (req, res) {
  res.render("contact", { contentContactpage: contactContent });
});
```

Links in HTML:

```
   <li id="home"><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
   <li id="about"><a href="/about">ABOUT US</a></li>
   <li id="contact"><a href="/contact">CONTACT US</a></li>
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Please make sure that the answer contains all the relevant information. Link only answers are not useful as the links may break over time.